# Why is my colleague getting my feature branch that is not merged yet in the main branch while doing a git pull?

Tags: git, github

Let's say there's a branch called releaseBranch.

I made featureBranch some days ago from releaseBranch. Today I completed my code changes in featureBranch and wanted to push it and then create a PR into releaseBranch. However I see there are conflicts now.. so I first rebased the releaseBranch in featureBranch. (I took the latest pull in the releaseBranch, checked out featureBranch, and used the command git rebase releaseBranch). Later I pushed the code to origin/featureBranch. I have not yet created a pull request yet.

A colleague of mine ran the command "git pull" in the release branch and it turns out they see the following output

```
From https://github.xyz.com/abc/def
 * [new branch]        featureBranch     -> origin/featureBranch
```

It just doesn't make any sense to me as I haven't created a pull request yet and they ran the git pull command in release branch.

Comment: Does your origin point to your fork or the common repository?

Comment: I don't understand what the surprise is. The way git works is that `fetch` completely syncs down all branches, period. If you push a branch, everyone can fetch it. That's just the way git is. If you don't want that to be possible, don't push, keep it local. But usually it doesn't cause any difficulty, because we all just cooperate in accordance with the rules.

Comment: @GauthamM my origin points to the common repository.

Comment: @matt I wouldn't have been surprised if they used command like "git pull origin featureBranch". My concern is - they merely used "git pull" from our releaseBranch and they got that output

Comment: @Raj Okay, since you have pushed to a common branch, others who have access to that branch would also be able to pull those changes

Comment: @GauthamM, I have not pushed to the common branch.. I pushed to origin/featureBranch which is not even merged into the release branch.

Comment: @GauthamM does rebasing releaseBranch into my featureBranch might have done something?

Comment: Just to add, I checked the commit history of the releaseBranch in the remote common repo and my commits of the featureBranch weren't present in the releaseBranch

Comment: In that case, are you sure that your colleague did not use `git pull origin featureBranch`

Comment: @GauthamM yes, I'm very sure as I saw it with my own eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Pull runs a fetch, which will update all other remote branches (like your featureBranch).... and that's what you see there. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Oh.. okay. I have just never seen another branch to be updated

Comment: That means that you probably were not paying attention (which is fine) or the branches hadn't moved since last pull or fetch at that moment.